# In Eclipse UNable to run the script in IE But IE its get launching

Tags: selenium

I am facing some issue with eclipse, I am running the script with TestNg, but it was unable to run the script itis hangover by launching IE application

Showing this message, nothing has been doing...

---

HI

I am facing some issue with eclipse, I am running the script with TestNg, but it was unable to run the script itis hangover by launching IE application

Showing this message, nothing has been doing...

---

18:09:04.942 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 23.2-b09
18:09:04.942 INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
18:09:04.953 INFO - v2.35.0, with Core v2.35.0. Built from revision c916b9d
18:09:05.087 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: 18:09:05.088 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
18:09:05.097 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
18:09:05.098 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
18:09:05.099 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
18:09:05.101 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@7de41969
18:09:05.101 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
18:09:05.104 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
18:09:05.104 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@3d9f242f
18:09:05.147 INFO - Checking Resource aliases
18:09:05.150 INFO - Command request: getNewBrowserSession[*iexplore, https://login.salesforce.com/, ] on session null
18:09:05.152 INFO - creating new remote session
18:09:05.163 INFO - Allocated session 4f8177c22aab4672a62cef88f6d66878 for https://login.salesforce.com/, launching...
jar:file:/C:/Selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar!/core
18:09:05.455 INFO - Launching Embedded Internet Explorer...

### 18:09:05.709 INFO - Launching Internet Explorer HTA...

Comment: Which IE version are you using? Also, are you sure that there is no firewall blocking?

Comment: What is the code used to launch IE?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your zoom is at 100%. Also in **Internet Options > security** you need to make sure that 'Enable protected mode' is selected on all 4 zones.